# Am I responsible for paying the full rent right away before actually viewing the apartment?

Tags: united-kingdom, housing, contracts

I am an international student moving to the UK very soon. I just signed a contract with an apartment **(APT1)**, which requires me to complete the entire payment (for 51 weeks).

The date I signed the contract (8/12) is actually later than the due date that appeared on the lease (8/8), so after signing the contract, the apartment sent me an email that informed me of a new due date (8/25). However, I'm not ready to send such a big payment as I don't have enough money in my bank account. The agent at the apartment told me they cannot hold my room too long due to the high volume of interest in booking the rooms.

I actually wanted to give up my tenancy on this contract, as a just found another apartment **(APT2)** that has a more reasonable payment requirement. However, on my current signed tenancy letter,

> Once you have signed this agreement you will be liable for the full rent set out in the agreement unless released from your tenancy by the Landlord or Management Company.

My question is do I have any legal responsibility to pay for the entire rent by the new due date (8/25) set by **APT1**? If they told me they cannot hold my booking any longer, do I need them to confirm **in writing** that I'm released from the agreement? I emailed them with my request but haven't received a response.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: IANAL but it looks to me as if you *are* liable for the full payment unless the landlord releases you from the tenancy. You will be in default if you don’t pay; the landlord will look to rent to someone else *and* obtain your payment. You need to get the release in writing.

Comment: Note, AFAIK, unlike a *tenancy deposit* that is returnable at the end of the tenancy, there is no restriction on the amount of rent in advance a landlord can ask for https://england.shelter.org.uk/professional_resources/legal/costs_of_renting/tenant_fees_and_other_costs/rent_in_advance_deposit_and_premium_fees

Comment: Cross-posted on LawSE - https://law.stackexchange.com/q/83554/35069